# Get pairs from a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable 'getDuplicates', which contains values like this:

```
getDuplicates = 100,120,450,490,600,650, ...
```

These are pairs and ranges: **1st**begin,**1st**end,**2nd**begin,**2nd**end

Now I have to loop them to apply these ranges.

```
    var getDuplicates = $element.attr('duplicates');
    if (getDuplicates !== undefined && getDuplicates !== null) {
        var noOfDuplicates = (getDuplicates.split(',').length) / 2;
        console.log(getDuplicates, 'Counter:', noOfDuplicates);
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfDuplicates; i++) {
            newRange = rangy.createRange();
            newRange.selectCharacters(rangyElement, **BEGIN, END**);
            var newApplier = rangy.createClassApplier(highlightClass, {
                elementTagName : "span"
            });
            newApplier.applyToRange(newRange);
        }
    }
```

Actually, I have no idea how to set BEGIN and END. Thank you for your tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the array with a for loop, using steps of 2 (`i += 2`). Get the start and end using the brackets (`[]`) notation.

Since the loop uses steps of 2, use `array.length` in the stop condition instead of the `noOfDuplicates`;

```js
var getDuplicates = "100,120,450,490,600,650";

// you need to split the string, so you'll have an array you can iterate
var duplicates = getDuplicates.split(','); 

for(var i = 0; i < duplicates.length; i += 2) {
  console.log(duplicates[i], duplicates[i + 1]); // 1st is start, 2nd is end
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: getDuplicates.split is not a function(…)'